# At least two answers per question reasonable?

Tags: discussion

If I remember correctly, one of the guidelines to help beta stack exchanges eventually earn full stack exchange status, is to have an average of two answers per question.  Certainly for questions that don't have clear cut answers or involve some opinion (e.g., "What is the best kind of telescope to view such-and-such?") this is reasonable, but for questions that have clear cut answers (e.g., "How massive is the sun?") one thorough and well-worded answer can often do a good enough job that any other answers to the question would be redundant.  For questions such as these, is it really reasonable to expect multiple answers?

I don't know if the questions I used as examples are actual questions on the site, I was just using them as examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there may be some questions that only require one, comprehensive, answer. For these we obviously don't want to encourage writing more answers just for the sake of increasing numbers.

The suggestion is really to have an average of 2 answers, so basically, for every question with one answer, we may have another more complex / less clear cut question with 3-4 answers on them.

We never *expect* you to have to go and make sure every question has at least 2 answers, so please don't feel it is required of you, especially as its more of a measurement statistic than a rule.

Hope this clears things up for you!